# Display facebook comments made on site

Tags: comments, facebook

Im using facebook comments for wordpress, now i would like to display the recent comment using the widget  but its getting an error Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in .. Is there other way to fetch the comments made from the posts and display them?

Answer (score 0):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/comment/ According to this you can query the comments can you convert this to wordpress query?